# How to run soap service in soapui(using wsdl) with password protection as like as in server?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

Actually, we are sending a soap response to one of our clients, It was deployed in Cisco service which we need to log in manually to check the WSDL and services If we want to test the same in soap UI how to set up it with password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to find out which kind of authentication you need to do. Maybe the guys that did the setup will be able to tell you that.

Then this tutorial will probably be able to help you:
https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html